# std::optional::value_or_default and std::optional::is_engaged

Tags: c++, c++17

I have been using the experimental `std::optional` for a while now and I was wondering if a method like `std::optional<T>::value_or_default`  had ever been considered. This would give you the value if engaged or a default `T` if not. Yes it easy to write `std::optional::value_or( T { } )` but sometimes if `T` has a bunch of characters I don't think it's as clear as writing `value_or_default`.

Also papers like n3672 don't really give a good reason why a method like `std:optional::is_engaged` was not included. I understand why `nullopt` is useful in some cases and was included but I think `std::optional::is_engaged` is clearer in simple if expressions.

Comment: Does `boost::optional` have these?

Comment: Also, testing whether the optional contains a value is easily done using the contextual conversion to `bool`, there's no need for `is_engaged` (and why use that term?  It appears nowhere in the documentation.  Parallel datatypes in other frameworks use "has value".)

Comment: `value_or_emplace` seems less special case than `_or_default`.  I'd argue that `value_or` should be `value_or_emplace` period (only construct the `or` if needed).  And `value_or()` would be the op you want.

Comment: @BenVoigt [N3672](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3672.html) and [`cppreference.com`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional) uses the “engaged” terminology.  So that term seems to be seriously considered by the committee.  As much as I agree that `has_value` would be a better name.  Finally, having such a member function would be consistent with `std::iostream::good` etc.

Comment: @goneskiing I'm not exactly sure what your question is.  While I find your remarks warranted, SO is probably not the best place to discuss “bike shed” questions concerning the standard library.  Could you maybe re-word your question such that it becomes more answerable and less discussion-oriented?  Or otherwise – if you *want* discussion – maybe consider posting to the respective [isocpp](https://isocpp.org/forums) mailing list.

Comment: Nowadays it’s `std::experimental::optional` and it is part of the Library Fundamentals TS ([recent document here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4335.html)). Note that the engaged/disengaged terminology has been phased out, the current phrasing is 'contains a value' or similar.

Comment: Does `value_or({})` without the class name not work?

Comment: @LB: No, `value_or({})` does not work, because the compiler cannot deduce what type to create from the brackets. `value_or` is a template, and will take any type that is convertible to what's supposed to be in the `optional`.

Comment: @MarshallClow I guess it's a good thing `optional` isn't set in stone yet, because that looks like a defect if I ever saw one.

Comment: @LB not really.  They should just change `value_or` to take varargs.  Then `.value_or()` does what you want `.value_or({})` to do.  Maybe add the `T&&` non-template overload in case we have something trying to deduce its evaluation context (making `{}` work again).

Comment: @LucDanton now cppreference phased out engaged/disengaged too

Comment: Alternatively, `T value_or(T&&)` and `T&& value_or(T&&)` overloads to permit `value_or` to accept `{}`s (which is what I do when I have an optional-like thing: easier emplace syntax).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an (minimally tested) implementation for you:

```
template <typename T>
T value_or_default (const std::experimental::optional<T> &s)
{ return s.value_or(T{}); }
```

Stick that in your code base, and you're done.